# Wrong Default Auto Text Leading

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Somehow I've messed up my default (Auto) line-height (leadning) in Photoshop.

It does more than double line spacing instead of the regular 1.5 or whatever it is. It's definitely not double by default thought. There are no new lines between the text and the paragraph tab is also zeroed out. The only way I can get around this is to copy text layers from older photoshop files.  Reset Character or Paragraph didn't fix it. Does it for all fonts and sizes.

Couldn't find anything on that topic online. Any clue what it might be? I hope it's not something stupid :)

### [Download .PSD](http://deepcorelabs.com/projects/so/ps/ps-wrong-leading-bug.psd)

PS CC (21.1.3)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *may be* the font itself.

The default "Auto" setting is 120% the type size for all Adobe applications. Some fonts that appears larger than expected, others smaller. It all depends on how the font is constructed. Depending upon *where* you got Arial.. well.. it maybe constructed poorly. It has to do with what is defined as the glyph box in the font construction.

Try.. **Paragraph Panel Menu** > Justification.

You'll find Auto-Leading set there....

[image]

Your file is set at 175%...

[image]

Comment: "Does it for all fonts and sizes." I think it started happening after trying Chinese & Japanese fonts recently. Can't figure it out... never seen it before.

Comment: Also, added psd file if you want to have a go at it.

Comment: @Miro check updated answer....

Comment: fcuk me never knew that existed. Must have been the chinses fonts that re-set that since they use 175% by default. Thanks a lot!